# Loading a Roslyn compiled assembly into a sandbox AppDomain

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've got a code-snippet that compiles a script with the script engine and I retreiv the assembly as a byte array.

Now I want to load this `Assembly` in a Sandbox, this is what I've got:

```
Assembly _dynamicAssembly;
ScriptEngine _engine;
Session _session;

public string Execute(string code)
{
    // Setup sandbox
    var e = new Evidence();
    e.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Internet));
    var ps = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(e);
    var setup = new AppDomainSetup 
                         { ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory };
    var domain = 
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", 
                               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup, ps);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += DomainAssemblyResolve;

    // Process code
    var submission = _engine.CompileSubmission<object>(code, _session);
    submission.Compilation.Emit(memoryStream);
    var assembly = memoryStream.ToArray();

    _dynamicAssembly = Assembly.Load(assembly);

    var loaded = domain.Load(assembly);

    // Rest of the code...
}
```

This is the event handler for AssemblyResolve:

```
Assembly DomainAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return _dynamicAssembly;
}
```

This means that when I do `domain.Load(assembly)` I will get the _dynamicAssembly, if I don't subscribe to that event and return that `Assembly`, I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

The above compiles and runs, but the problem is that code that is executed in the domain-assembly is not actually executed in the sandbox. When I get the submission-method and invoke the factory in it and return this `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` the result is: `MyRoslynApplication.vshost.exe` which is **not** the sandbox `AppDomain`

Am I loading my `byte[]`-assembly wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to load a type that runs in the sandbox and access it from your main AppDomain, you'll need to use a method like [CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h7t2a2.aspx).  The type will need to be a MarshalByRefObject so that it can create a transparent proxy in the calling AppDomain for access.

If the main AppDomain resolves the assembly, it will be loaded into the main AppDomain (as well as the sandbox AppDomain) so that you end up with two copies loaded.  Your main AppDomain must always remain insulated from the sandbox via proxies, so that only MarshalByRefObject and serializable objects can be accessed.  Note that the type you're referencing also cannot be defined in the assembly you want to load into the sandbox; you'll want to define interfaces and possibly serializable types in a third common assembly, which will then be loaded into both the main and sandbox AppDomains.

---

I've done some additional digging and it looks like all the methods for loading an assembly into another AppDomain and generating a proxy require an assembly name to resolve.  I'm not sure if it's possible to load via a byte[] in this case; you might need to save the assembly to disk and load that.  I'll dig a bit more.

---

I think you can do this (this is untested, but it seems plausible).

These would need to be in an 'interface' assembly accessible to both your main app and the sandbox (I'll refer to it as Services.dll):

```
public interface IMyService
{
    //.... service-specific methods you'll be using
}

public interface IStubLoader
{
    Object CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(byte[] assemblyBytes, string typeName);
}
```

Next is a class in a StubLoader.dll.  You won't reference this assembly directly; this is where you'll call the first AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap, providing this as the assembly name and StubLoader as the type name.

```
public sealed class StubLoader: MarshalByRefObject, IStubLoader
    {
        public object CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(byte[] assemblyBytes, string typeName)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
            return assembly.CreateInstance(typeName);
        }
    }
```

Now, to use it from your main AppDomain, you do this:

```
//Create transparent proxy for the stub loader, which will live in the sandbox
var stubLoader = (IStubLoader)sandboxDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("Stubloader.dll", "StubLoader");

//Have the stub loader marshal a proxy to a dynamically loaded assembly (via byte[]) where MyService is the type name implementing MarshalByRefObject and IMyService
var myService = (IMyService)stubLoader.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyBytes, "MyService");
```

Unfortunately, AppDomains are not simple to use.  This is because they provide a high degree of insulation and therefore require proxying to allow for usage across AppDomain boundaries.

---

In response to how you could marshal a non-serializable and non-MarshalByRefObject class, here is a rough example of what might be in the shared interface DLL:

```
public interface ISessionWrapper
{
    void DoSomethingWithSession();
}

public sealed class SessionWrapper : MarshalByRefObject, ISessionWrapper
{
    private readonly Session _session;

    public SessionWrapper(Session session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithSession()
    {
        //Do something with the wrapped session...
        //This executes inside the sandbox, even though it can be called (via proxy) from outside the sandbox
    }
}
```

Now everywhere your original service needed to work with Session, it can instead pass ISessionWrapper, whose calls will be marshalled behind the scenes so that all of the actual code executes in the sandbox on a real Session instance living in the sandbox.

Comment: How would that work when the Assembly is not on disk? `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` requires a physical file, no? **Edit** in response to your edit, I can't load from disk since that would require IO Permissions.

Comment: @Filip, would you be able to use some form of isolated storage?  I'm guessing not, since that doesn't allow a file name.

Comment: @Filip, the only idea coming to me at this moment would be to use some roundabout mechanism whereby the byte[] gets communicated via some cross-process or cross-domain mechanism (such as storing it in Isolated Storage or communicating it over a port), then have a 'stub loader' assembly that you can reference by name.  It would then start up, access the byte[] through this outside medium, then return the wrapped proxy.

Comment: Wow... really? That seems Way to "complicated" for what I want to do, specially with all this nice roslyn things out there. I really just want to run a "script" in the Script Engine with limited priviligies.

Comment: @Filip, I think there is a slightly easier way, as byte[] is serializable, so you won't need to use an outside data transport mechanism.  I've proposed a generic mechanism to work around the fact that the BCL doesn't include a byte[] overload for AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap.  If you can get this to work and find any issues with what I posted, please go ahead and edit the post.

Comment: Well I've come a bit further here, however, I can't create an instance of the type inside the `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` method because there is no public constructor defined. Since this is just a code line that I am executing like this: `var x = 10; x == 10` see outputted IL here: http://privatepaste.com/4cfe2db1ad

Comment: Running this now, got a bit further: `return assembly.CreateInstance("Submission#1", true, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, null, new [] {Session.Create()}, new CultureInfo("neutral"), null);` however, this complains about it being security transparent: "In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.". Wouldn't making it fully trusted defeat the purpose?

Comment: @Filip, I think you may need to do some more research on AppDomains and MarshalByRefObject.  Aside from the awkwardness of loading from a `byte[]`, you'll still need to do some design work to figure out how to proxy an interface that adapts your 'script' for use by your application.  At the very least, you need a MarshalByRefObject and some form of interface for your service that's independent of the dynamically loaded assembly.

Comment: @Filip, I hadn't considered how the security permissions fit in; I recommend posting that as a new question.  It's unfortunately outside my expertise.

Comment: Well the above question isn't really solved and I think the permission stuff fits in here since it's most likely what I need to accomplish to get it working.
The problem is that the generated code ( in the byte[] assembly ) uses types that are not serializable, thus, I can't create an instance of it..
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the help Dan, your code would work in any other normal circumstance. But when it comes to the way that I did it with roslyn, I can't pass for instance a `Session` down to the other app domain, because it is not serializable and requires that compilation and execution is made in the same app domain.

Comment: @Filip, one thought is that you could create a wrapper MarshalByRefObject that encapsulates the operations you need to perform with the Session, then pass that SessionWrapper to your script.  Now you can construct the SessionWrapper in your main AppDomain, pass it to the method (which marshals it as a proxy to the script), which can then operate with the proxy (where its methods get marshalled back to your main AppDomain for execution.)

Comment: Do you think you could write up an example of how that would work?

Comment: Brilliant answer.  You clarified a lot of confusion for me.  The `StubLoader` technique is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

probably this could also help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox

Also I had to persist the created assembly file stream onto the disk to get the Sandbox working. I'm still struggling with Strong naming and unit testing of the solution (there are over 16 projects), however, I'll get back to you with the working copy.