# Roslyn - Scripting API - execute script in an isolated domain

Tags: c#, roslyn

As far as I can understand, the roslyn scripting API is loading the script to the current AppDomain.

```
CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("System.DateTime.Today.Year")
    .ContinueWith(s => result = s.Result).Wait();
```

There's any method to load it to a new AppDomain so in the end I can dispose/discard it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works for you?

[Loading a Roslyn compiled assembly into a sandbox AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312974/loading-a-roslyn-compiled-assembly-into-a-sandbox-appdomain)

Also, since Roslyn is .net native, everything is supposed to be managed by GC. If that's the case, the boilerplate code required for creating and unloading an Appdomain would be way too much.